# Link functions used with binomial error distribution

Tags: r, statistics

When you have a binomial error distribution what link functions can you use on r? Also how would describe the link functions as well, as I want to get a greater understanding of them so when it comes to applying them I know what is best suited to my questions.

Comment: More appropriate for a statistics forum.

Comment: See the `?family` help page for what families and link functions R supports.